# Java JFrame paint method display flickers

Tags: java, swing, timer, paint, display

while using paint from JFrame, my display flickers a lot. I can't make it stop and I would love to know how to make it stop flickering. I also tried to add the swing.timer here, but its still doesn't do anything.
package Game;

```
public class Play extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener, ActionListener {
    
    private int _xPad,_yPad,_xdir,_ydir;
    private Brick[][] _bricks;
    private Ball _gameBall;
    private Timer _timer;
    
    public Play(int[][] board){
        super("Elemental Brick Breaker");
        _xdir = 0;
        _ydir = 0;
        _xPad = 350;
        _yPad = 500;
        _timer = new Timer(1000,this);
        _timer.start();
        _gameBall = new FireBall(_xPad,_yPad);
        _bricks = new Brick[8][10];
        int x = 75, y = 40;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
                _bricks[i][j] = new FireBrick(x,y);
                x = x + 65;
                }
            y = y + 25;
            x = 75;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillRect(_xPad, _yPad, 120, 10);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
                g.fillRect(_bricks[i][j].getX(), _bricks[i][j].getY() , 60, 20);
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a lightweight component (such as a JPanel) and override it's `paintComponent` method. See [the Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: "Swing programs should override paintComponent():" JFrame does not have paintComponent - what do you say to that??

Comment: @gpasch: `JFrame` is just the top-level container; the citation _used_ used to link to the [`SwingPaintDemo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this approach:

have a separate image to draw things on:

```
im=createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
```

in constructor.

Then in paint:

```
Graphics g2=im.getGraphics();
```

and apply all commands relagated to g on g2:

```
g2.fillRect etc
```

then draw the image on g:

```
g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, this);
```

in short:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics g2=im.getGraphics();
    g2.fillRect(_xPad, _yPad, 120, 10);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
            g2.fillRect(_bricks[i][j].getX(), _bricks[i][j].getY() , 60, 20);
            }

    g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

and have an update method:

```
public void update(Graphics g) { paint(g); }
```

--

I have simplified your class as follows: - it does not produce flicker - if I put it back as you have it it produces flicker.

```
class Play extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private int _xPad,_yPad,_xdir,_ydir;
private Rectangle[][] _bricks;
//    private Ball _gameBall;
private javax.swing.Timer _timer;
Image im;

public Play(){
    super("Elemental Brick Breaker");
    setSize(1000, 500);
    _xdir = 0;
    _ydir = 0;
    _xPad = 350;
    _yPad = 500;
    _timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000,this);
    _timer.start();
//        _gameBall = new FireBall(_xPad,_yPad);
    _bricks = new Rectangle[8][10];
    int x = 75, y = 40;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
            _bricks[i][j] = new Rectangle(x,y, 60, 20);
            x = x + 65;
            }
        y = y + 25;
        x = 75;
    }
    setVisible(true);
    im=createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics g2=im.getGraphics();
    g2.fillRect(_xPad, _yPad, 120, 10);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
            g2.fillRect(_bricks[i][j].x, _bricks[i][j].y , 60, 20);
            }
    }
    g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, this);
}

public void update(Graphics g) { paint(g); }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  repaint();
  System.out.println("t");
}
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work, where should i invoke the update method?

Comment: I would highly recommend reading about [Painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). You should not override `update` or `paint` - rather paint via a lightweight component (like `JPanel`) and override its `paintComponent` method

Answer (score 1):

Do not override `paint` or `update`. Painting should be done using a lightweight component and overriding its `paintComponent` method. For example:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //custom painting
    }
}
//elsewhere in your code - add the JPanel to the JFrame
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(myPanel );
```

If you wish to repaint upon some type of event, call repaint on the instance. For instance, within the implementation of an ActionListener:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    myPanel.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your paint method, do

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Comment: its says that this method is undefined for Graphics.

Comment: it acually made it flicker ever more